# Securely store data for multiple party's in a single table

Tags: database, database-design

I'm certainly no DBA and only a beginner when it comes to software development, so any help is appreciated. What is the most secure structure for storing the data from multiple parties in one database? For instance if three people have access to the same tables, I want to make sure that each person can only see their data. Is it best to create a unique ID for each person and store that along with the data then query based on that ID? Are there other considerations I should take into account as well?

Comment: read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx . I would go tenant per schema (if using mysql, a mysql "database" is really just a database schema).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but mapping the USER ID into the table is probably not what you want, because in practice many users have access to the corporations data.  In those cases you would store "CorpID" as a column, or more generically "ContextID".  But yes, to limit access to data, each row should be able to convey who the data is for, either directly (the row actually contains a reference to CorpID, UserID, ContextID or the like) or it can be inferred by joining to other tables that reference the qualifier.

In practice, these rules are enforced by a middle tier that queries the database, providing the user context in some way so that only the correct records are selected out of the database and ultimately presented to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> ...three people have access to the same tables...

If these persons can query the tables directly through some query tool like toad then we have a serious problem. if not, that is like they access through some middle tier/service layer or so then @wagregg's solution above holds.

coming to the case when they have direct access rights then one approach is:

1. create database level user accounts for each of the users.
2. have another table with row level grant information. say `your_table` has a primary key column `MY_PK_COL` then the structure of the `GRANTS_TABLE` table would be like `{USER_ID; MY_PK_COL}` with `MY_PK_COL` a foreign key to `your_table`.
3. Remove all privileges of concerned users from your_table
4. Create a view. `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE user_id=getCurrentUserID();`
5. give your users SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE rights on this view.

Most of the database systems (MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer) provide way to get current logged user. (the one used in the connection string). They also provide ways to restrict access to certain tables. now for your users the view will behave as a normal table. they will never know the difference.

a problem happens when there are too many users. provisioning a database level uer account to every one of them may turn difficult. but then DBMS like MsSQLServer can use windows authentication, there by reducing the user/creation problem.

In most of the scenarios the *filter at middle tier* approach is the best way. but there are times when security is paramount. Also a bug in the middle tier may allow malicious users to bypass the security. SQL injection is one thing to name. then you have to do what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about a multi-tenant architecture, but I can't tell for sure.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068254/562459) has a summary of the issues, and links to an online article containing details about the trade-offs.